# PostgreSQL Connection Reset by Peer Errors

Tags: postgresql, docker, error-handling, connection, docker-swarm

I recently updated my postgreSQL version to 12.15-bullseye. Everything went smooth but a couple days after I started noticing these logs:

```
2023-09-06 07:12:02.607 PDT [68784] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2023-09-06 07:12:49.342 PDT [71207] ERROR:  function aurora_version() does not exist at character 8
2023-09-06 07:12:49.342 PDT [71207] HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
2023-09-06 07:12:49.342 PDT [71207] STATEMENT:  select AURORA_VERSION() as aurora_version
2023-09-06 07:14:00.367 PDT [68964] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2023-09-06 07:15:20.239 PDT [68962] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer`
```

The aurora error, from my research, can be ignored, as this appears to be some sort of a bug, but I'd like to fix the connection reset by peer error.

I tried looking at my databases here:

```
>     Name    |   Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |    Access privileges    
> ------------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------------  bitbucket  | bitbucket | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |  
> confluence | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
> =Tc/postgres           +
>             |           |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres  +
>             |           |          |            |            | confluence=CTc/postgres  dtrack     | postgres  | UTF8     |
> en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =Tc/postgres           +
>             |           |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres  +
>             |           |          |            |            | dtrack=CTc/postgres  grafana    | grafana   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 |
> en_US.utf8 |   jira       | jira      | UTF8     | C.UTF-8    |
> C.UTF-8    |   keycloak   | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 |
> en_US.utf8 | =Tc/postgres           +
>             |           |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres  +
>             |           |          |            |            | keycloak=CTc/postgres  postgres   | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8
> | en_US.utf8 |   sonarqube  | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 |
> en_US.utf8 | =Tc/postgres           +
>             |           |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres  +
>             |           |          |            |            | sonarqube=CTc/postgres  template0  | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8
> | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres            +
>             |           |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres  template1  | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8
> | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres            +
>             |           |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres  vault      | postgres  | UTF8     | en_US.utf8
> | en_US.utf8 | =Tc/postgres           +
>             |           |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres  +
>             |           |          |            |            | vault=CTc/postgres (11 rows)
```

But I don't see where the connection is being reset.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot and fix this?

Comment: There is certainly no reason to thing that pg_database will help you. Enhance your logging (log_line_prefix) so that it logs the username, application name, database name, and hostname/address.